# Flutter FadeIn/FadeOut animation together

Tags: flutter, fadein, flutter-animation, fadeout

in this simple sample code i want to have fadeIn and fadeOut animation together, but in this code fadeIn work only and `reverse` not work, how can i have both of them together?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main()=>runApp(MaterialApp(home: FadeTransitionSample(),));
class FadeTransitionSample extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _Fade();
}

class _Fade extends State<FadeTransitionSample> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  AnimationController animation;
  Animation<double> _fadeInFadeOut;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    animation = AnimationController(vsync: this, duration: Duration(seconds: 3),);
    _fadeInFadeOut = Tween<double>(begin: 0.0, end: 0.1).animate(animation);

    animation.addListener((){
      if(animation.isCompleted){
        animation.reverse();
      }else{
        animation.forward();
      }
    });
    animation.repeat();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        child: Center(
          child: FadeTransition(
            opacity: animation,
            child: Container(
              color: Colors.green,
              width: 100,
              height: 100,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Alright, I am assuming, you are looking to get a FadeIn & FadeOut animation on your container.

There are a few things you need to change.

1. The `FadeTransition` class should not take the `animation` for opacity, rather it should be the `_fadeInFadeOut` variable
2. The animation starts, when you call the `animation.forward()` rather than `animation.repeat()` (Since in your case, you also need to reverse the animation, always start with the animation.forward() call).

Make sure to use the `addStatusListener()` method instead of `addListener()` since you get much better control over your states.

So, all of this put together, below is the working code to make your animation work.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main()=>runApp(MaterialApp(home: FadeTransitionSample(),));
class FadeTransitionSample extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _Fade();
}

class _Fade extends State<FadeTransitionSample> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  AnimationController animation;
  Animation<double> _fadeInFadeOut;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    animation = AnimationController(vsync: this, duration: Duration(seconds: 3),);
    _fadeInFadeOut = Tween<double>(begin: 0.0, end: 0.5).animate(animation);

    animation.addStatusListener((status){
      if(status == AnimationStatus.completed){
        animation.reverse();
      }
      else if(status == AnimationStatus.dismissed){
        animation.forward();
      }
    });
    animation.forward();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        child: Center(
          child: FadeTransition(
            opacity: _fadeInFadeOut,
            child: Container(
              color: Colors.green,
              width: 100,
              height: 100,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks. how can i set delay between forward and reverse?

Comment: Currently, the delay is the same for both the FadeIn and Fade Out. If you want to have a different duration for two actions, you have to create separate animations and use them. Can't do it with a simple reverse method. There are other calls like animateTo() and animateBack() which you can look to leverage.

Comment: I can never thank you and upvote you enough, man!
Took my the whole day, to do something that can be done in mere minutes on Android (Java: view.animate()....) all because I wanted to make the title in the appBar fade out then back in when a different screen is selected from the bottomNavBar. Thank you man, almost 5 years later, but THANK YOU!

Answer (score 4):

**Option #1**

Simple solution and straight forward with less code, the idea is to combine `FadeOut` inside `FadeIn` and give the `FadeOut` delay amount greater than the duration of the `FadeIn`, just copy and paste then just change the `Image.asset` widget to anything you want to fade in/out

1- Add [this package](https://pub.dev/packages/animate_do).

2- Import it in your page `import 'package:animate_do/animate_do.dart';`

3- Add this Widget:

```
Widget _animateLogo() {
  return Container(
    child: FadeIn(
        animate: true,
        duration: Duration(seconds: 2),

        child: FadeOut(
          animate: true,
          delay: Duration(seconds: 2),
          duration: Duration(seconds: 1),

          // Just change the Image.asset widget to anything you want to fade in/out:
          child: Image.asset(
            "assets/images/logo.png",
            height: 150,
            width: 150,
            fit: BoxFit.contain,
          ), //Image.asset

        ) // FadeOut
    ),
  );
}
```

**Option #2:**

Use native class `AnimatedOpacity` class with `setState`:

```
// 1- Declare
bool _shouldFade = false;

// 2- Animation fucntion
Widget _animateLogo() {
  return AnimatedOpacity(
    duration: Duration(milliseconds: 200),
    opacity: _shouldFade ? 1 : 0,
    child: Container(
      // Whatever you want to fadein fadeout
    ),
  );
}

// 3- Animate whenever needed
setState(() {
  // Fade in
  _shouldFade = true;
});

// Fadeout after 3 seconds
Future.delayed(
  Duration(seconds: 3),
  () => setState(() {
        _shouldFade = false;
  }),
);
```

Comment: You have to provide more details in your answers. There is no `FadeIn/Out` widgets in Flutter.

Comment: I updated the answer with more details, thanks for noticing!